# How to post same names for file and parameter name by php curl CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS?

Tags: php, curl, post

I post file and parameter by curl command to t.php:

**t.php:**

```
<?php

print_r( $_FILES );
print_r( $_POST );
?>
```

it's need the same names for file and parameter "name":

```
curl http://localhost/t.php -X POST -F "name=@D:\file.zip" -F "name=test"
```

result is:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [name] => file.zip
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => D:\www\tmp\php653B.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 150
        )

)
Array
(
    [name] => test
)
```

it is ok!

But,
How to post same names for file and parameter name by php curl CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS?

```
//
$data = [
    'name' => curl_file_create('D:\file.zip'),
    //'name' => 'test', // <--- ?????????????
];

$curl = curl_init('http://localhost/t.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
$out = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Help me, please

Answer (score 0):

```
$boundary = '---'.time().'---' ;
$header = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary='.$boundary;

$filename = 'D:\file.zip';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($filename);
$content =  "--". $boundary . "\r\n".
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"; filename=\"".basename($filename)."\"\r\n".
            "Content-Type: application/zip\r\n\r\n".
            $file_contents."\r\n";
$content .= "--". $boundary. "\r\n".
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"\r\n\r\n".
            "test\r\n";
$content .= "--" . $boundary . "--\r\n";
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
          'method' => 'POST',
          'header' => $header,
          'content' => $content,
    )
));
$result = file_get_contents('http://localhost/t.php', false, $context);
```

Answer (score -2):

Prepare the array of data something like below:

```
$data = array('name' => 'Foo', 'file' => '@/home/user/test.png');
```

> Notice: `@` is appended before the file path.

The following example taken from php.net.

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

$data = array('name' => 'Foo', 'file' => '@/home/user/test.png');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/upload.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_exec($ch);
?>
```